# Auto rotate in open3D with Python

Tags: python-3.x, open3d

I am trying to generate a 360 view of my 3D model for easier visualization.

Using the tutorial in open3d documentation, I made a code, but if I can save each frame, then make a gif without any trouble, I cannot make the model rotate.

I am on Python3.8 and open3d 0.17.0

```
    global superindex
    superindex = 0
    rot = 10
    
    def rotate_view(vis):
        global superindex
        if superindex == 0:
            ro = vis.get_render_option()
            ro.mesh_show_back_face = True
            #ro.show_coordinate_frame = True
        
        ctr = vis.get_view_control()
        ctr.rotate(float(rot), 0.)
        superindex += rot
        
        vis.capture_screen_image(r"D:\folder\folder\folder\{:05d}.png".format(superindex))

        if superindex >= 2090:
            vis.close()
        return False
    
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries_with_animation_callback(meshes,
                                                              rotate_view)
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks